# Having trouble with MYSQL IN() function

Tags: php, mysql, pear

I am building a dynamic news application for a site. The news will be split up into categories which may then contain subcategories(which may contain subcategories) and news articles. I have created a recursive function to return all of the category IDs for all subcategories of a certain category. I would like to run a single query to grab all of the news posts whose category is in the set that was returned by the recursive function.

When I try to use this (I'M USING PEAR DB)

```
//$myReturnedIDs is a comma delimited list of ids. 5,6,7,8,10,12

$oPrep = $oConn->prepare("SELECT NewsID FROM SiteNews WHERE NewsCategory IN (?)");

$oRes = $oConn->execute($oPrep, array($myReturnedIDs));
```

The resulting query looks like this:

```
SELECT NewsID FROM SiteNews WHERE NewsCategory IN('5,6,7,8,10,12')
```

while I need it to look like:

```
SELECT NewsID FROM SiteNews WHERE NewsCategory IN(5,6,7,8,10,12)
```

Now, I realize I could populate that portion of the query in the prepare statement, but I feel that leads to some possible hole for an attack. Am I being over cautious, since the data is not user generated? Is there some way to make this work? My other thought was to add a ? for each ID, amount would be determined before the prepare statement (after getting all the IDs), but that feels clunky to me. Any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP PDO: Can I bind an array to an IN() condition?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/920353/php-pdo-can-i-bind-an-array-to-an-in-condition)

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess that `$myReturnedIDs` is a comma-delimited *string*.  So this:

```
array($myReturnedIDs)
```

yields a one-element array:

```
["5,6,7,8,10,12"]
```

If that's the case, then you want to use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to make the array you want:

```
$oRes = $oConn->execute($oPrep, explode(",", $myReturnedIDs));
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: With PEAR execute, the number of parameters in the prepared statement must equal the count of the argument array. This results in a mismatch error.

Comment: @MichaelWheeler - I think I misinterpreted `execute`'s arguments.  Try using `array(explode(",", $myReturnedIDs))` instead.  If that's works, I'll fix it in my answer, too.  Cheers!

Comment: I still get the mismatch error. Im looking through http://stackoverflow.com/questions/920353/php-pdo-can-i-bind-an-array-to-an-in-condition as it seems my problem is a duplicate of that.

Comment: Dang.  Would have been convenient...  One other thought - if you trust the source of `$myReturnedIDs`, you can use `!` instead of `?` in [prepare](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.database.db.intro-execute.php) to substitute an argument it in without escaping it.  But that's all I got.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts! Realistically, there should be no way of an ID coming up that would mess with any queries (All ID's are automatically generated when an admin creates a subcategory), so the data should be sanitary!